# Pusher Ajax call doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, backbone.js, pusher

Trying to use [Pusher](http://pusher.com/docs/) for the first time and.. not sure if it is working or not.

When the page loads, the `console.log` statements I've put in the `js` code fire, showing that the `Pusher` object goes through the following states: `Initialized > Connecting > Connected`

However, I've bound a simple ajax call to the `connected` event hoping to just send, and then receive, the `Pusher.connection.socked_id`. Once in the `success` function of the ajax call I just want to display the returned `socket_id`.

Again, all my displays show up in the console and make the app appear to be working, including the `Successful Ajax Call` message in the `success` callback, however I am not receiving any data. The `data` object displays as `undefined`, and if I set a breakpoint in the `HandleEvent` server-side method it never fires.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**C#**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void HandleEvent(string socket_id)
    {
        var pusher = new Pusher(PusherConfig.APP_ID(), PusherConfig.KEY(), PusherConfig.SECRET());
        var result = pusher.Trigger("test_channel", "my_event", new { message = socket_id });
    }
```

**Pusher App**

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
Pusher.log = function(message) {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
       console.log(message);
    }
};

var pusher = new Pusher(key);
var socketId = null;
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function (data) {
    alert(data.message);
});
pusher.connection.bind('initialized', function (data) {
    console.log('initialized');
});
pusher.connection.bind('connecting', function (data) {
    console.log('connecting');
});
pusher.connection.bind('connected', function (data) {
    console.log('connected');
    socketId = pusher.connection.socket_id;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/Values/HandleEvent',
        type: "POST",
        data: { socket_id: socketId },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Succesful Ajax Call");
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Bad Ajax Call");
        }
    });
});
pusher.connection.bind('unavailable', function (data) {
    console.log('unavailable');
});
pusher.connection.bind('failed', function (data) {
    console.log('failed');
});
pusher.connection.bind('disconnected', function (data) {
    console.log('disconnected');
});
console.log("State: " + pusher.connection.state);
```

});

Comment: I'd recommend providing the output of the Pusher JavaScript library debug log. See https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging

Comment: Are you able to call "api/Values/HandleEvent" manually with a fake socket ID (perhaps with curl) and receive the correct response? That would be the first thing to test.

Answer (score 0):

since response is returning in json, please try the following commands.

to view full response

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

to view the message only

```
alert( data.message);
```